# import of amqp from org.springframework get error

Tags: spring, scala, amqp

I'm working on existing Scala project which using the spring framework and I need to import org.springframework.amqp but when I tried to build the project I get:

> Error:(15, 28) object amqp is not a member of package
>   org.springframework import org.springframework.amqp

It is really strange since I can see it in the formal website and I can see it in lot of examples in the web.

Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: can you add your sbt file, dependency versions, etc. Also try `sbt clean compile`. It may be version conflict between compile dependencies.

Comment: actually, I'm using maven. What dependency should I use for this import?

Comment: Thanks to your comment I focus on maven and found what was missing. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Maven dependency was missing. This is what I was need to add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-amqp</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```